# Carrying out a BlastP on ORF and achieving hits but 2 have the exact same score, evalue and query cover?

Tags: bioinformatics

I'm working on a project in my university and we were all given different sequences to work off of. I am meant to compare my blastN to my blastP result. However, when I carried out my blasP I got many hits but the top 2 hits had 100 percent cover, 100 percent identity and 0.0 evalue. I am meant to work off of one of the species I achieved from blastp to compare to blastN. How do I know which one to compare to see what's most significant to my blastn species? I have to continue on and use clustalw and phylogeny after so I need to be sure.

Comment: We can't help really help unless we know the sequences you are working with. Please [edit] your question and show us i) your query protein and nucleotide sequences and ideally ii) the HSPs (the matching sequences) you found. That said, you could always just compare both. Running a blastN is not very hard or time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you have two subject protein sequences that are exactly the same as your query. You say they are different species, so I guess you made sure they are not the same species and different strains, or subspecies.

I would suggest to now query your nucleotide sequence using blastn against both results (since a priori it could be either species, or neither), and focus on the one that gets a higher score using blastn in your phylogenetic analysis. Due to codon degeneracy, it could be that your blastn results differ between the two.